# Sistema de upload de fotos, nao aparace nome em banco de dados, mas a imagen se direciona para a pasta de dentro do servidor

Tags: php, mysql

olá, estou tentando fazer upload de imagens para meu site, através de um php, com o script eu consigo jogar a img dentro da pasta que quero dentro do servidor, todavia em meu banco de dados n aparece que um aquivo foi adcionado, abaixo estao as imagens das linhas, ja havia feio no mesmo site um sistema de cadastro em que funciona certinho e aparace a linha nova na tabela sempre que ocorre um cadastro, por favor me ajudem.

grato desde já.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código ao invés da imagem dele. Isso ajuda quem for lhe ajudar.

Comment: Utilize `mysqli_error($conn);` após a `query` para ver se há algum erro.